# Multibinding on Windows 10 UWP

Tags: uwp, multibinding

Will multibinding be supported on Windows 10 UWP in a feature update? Or will the Compiled Data Binding support multibinding in the future?

I have two textboxes, and I would like to sum their content, divide it by 100, and store it in a third textbox using multibinding.

Any ideas?

Comment: `{x:Bind}` can be used with methods, not just properties. Should be trivial to implement a method in your view class that calculates the sum, divides it by 100, and returns the result for consumption in the XAML markup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Anniversary update of the Windows SDK this summer the call of a method with multiple properties will be possible. Then you can use that for the third textbox.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you realy need multibinding to achieve this. An fairly simple viewmodel will do great.

Answer (score 0):

not avaible in uwp standards yet.but Cimbalino Toolkit can do it.